# Unable to create a file with log4j

Tags: java, spring, logging, configuration

Currently my code is printing logs on the console, yet it's not creating a file with the logs. This is the code of log4j.properties:

```
log4j.rootLogger=file, stdout

log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=C:/logs/logging.log
log4j.appender.file.ImmediateFlush=true
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %L - %m%n
log4j.appender.file.Append=true
log4j.appender.file.Threshold=INFO

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %m%n
```

It's in the resource folder of my spring application.
And this is where i use it:

```
public void getPreviousDay() {
        PropertyConfigurator.configure("log4j.properties");
        logger = Logger.getLogger(LocationScheduler.class);
        logger.info("Test");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are couple of changes you need to make to your `log4j.properties`

1. First of all `log4j.rootLogger` specifies Log Level and than the appender. so in your case it has to be

   `log4j.rootLogger= INFO, file, stdout`
2. Instead of `log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender` use `log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender` in order to get a rollover logfile.

Hope this helps.

**EDIT**

It seems your program is not able to reach your `log4j.properties` and the reason is the method you are using for loading it only takes a fully qualified path of the `log4j.properties`

If you want to load your `log4j.properties` from classpath use below version:

```
 PropertyConfigurator.configure(ClassLoader.getSystemResource("log4j.properties"));
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion and corrected my code, unfortunately it didn't work :(

Comment: Are you sure your log4j.properties is reachable for loading?

Comment: Finally i found the answer, pretty simple actually. I had named the file log4j.property when I renamed it, it created the file. So thanks for the help :)

Comment: By the way can you give me a hint how to write only a specific message to the file. I mean i don't want all the logs to be saved only a specific string

Comment: Please ask a separate question for this.